# API rails app import CSV into database through REST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, csv, import

Using Postman to upload to a POST path in a rails app (api only) however not sure how to parse it into the rails app.

We have a model to import the table with a import method that takes a CSV and loops through to add it to the db.

however not sure how to take the file through the post in the controller using the params[] since we are posting it as binary (we have tried the form way in Postman too with not much luck).

I have in the controller

`file = CSV.read(params[:file].path)`

however this makes an array which I don't quite know how to feed into the model (there are headers in the original CSV file too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you can upload your csv to S3, or Dropbox, then just post the url to server, server reads that CSV and import to DB.

Here is example to read CSV from a URL:

**app/services/process_csv.rb**

```
require 'csv'
require 'net/http'

class ProcessCsv    
  def initialize(csv_url)
    @csv_url = csv_url
  end

  def proesss
    uri = URI(@csv_url)
    csv_text = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
    csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, headers: true)
    csv.each do |row|
      # Process row here and import to DB here
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can use `ProcessCsv` in your controller, the params of your controller is just an URL to CSV file, not CSV data!

Answer (score 0):

You can parse `CSV` using foreach. For example, something like given below.

```
CSV.foreach(params[:file].path, headers: false) do |row|
  Model.create(name: row[0], email: row[1])
end
```